# IntelliJ Javascript Debug Generated File Names

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea

Is it possible for intellij to automatically resolve generated javascript files? For example, I have a javascript file called `uiComponents.js` but when I actually deploy to my tomcat the browser recognizes it as `uiComponents.js?=1367435289202`. Is there a way for intellij to recognize that they are the same thing?

Comment: No, but now we have a build process that makes it impossible any way.